# Interesting inequality $\|F\|_p\le \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/p)}\|f\|_p$ over $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, inequality, convolution

Consider the function $$F(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)}{x+y} \, dy, \quad0<x<\infty$$

Prove that if $1<p<\infty$, $$\|F\|_p\le \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/p)}\|f\|_p$$ and show that the constant is the best possible.

---

Since this problem came from a chapter on convolution, I think it might help to rewrite the integral in the form of a convolution over $\mathbb{R}$. I'm thinking of setting $z=x+y$ so that $y=z-x$.

Also, to evaluate the constant, this might be helpful:

for $0<a<1$, $$\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+x)x^a} \, dx=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi a}$$

Somewhat related: [Prove $ F(x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{x+y}dy $ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and differentiable, and have $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} F(x)=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381451/prove-fx-int-0-infty-fracfyxydy-is-continuous-on-0-infty-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358861/hilberts-inequality/359288#359288) we know that
$$
\Vert F\Vert\leq \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+t)t^{1/p}}dt
$$
From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-of-integral/110478#110478) we know that the last integral equals
$$
\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/p)}
$$

Comment: Thank you! But how do we show the constant is the best possible?

Comment: This wa not asked in the original question. You can try [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384546/show-that-the-linear-operator-tfx-frac1-pi-int-0-infty-fracfy?lq=1) but it heavily uses that $p=2$.